# Responsive CSS works everywhere except the Internet Browser on Droid Phone (Galaxy S4)

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, galaxy

I have got my website working everywhere except the default "Internet" browser on the Droid phone. It looks great in Chrome on the phone. It passes all the Google tests for mobile ready. It looks good on iPhone. Here's the site ... http://beavercreekmarina.com.

It's driving me crazy. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i put this code in

```
<head> 

 <!--[if (gt IE ) | (IEMobile)]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ie.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and made css code just for ie